# What do we do with Googleable Questions?

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette, flagging

How should we best deal with questions that are easily Googleable or not very useful? A downvote and a comment? Flag it as low quality? Something else? This for example: [Who is the person behind Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/156/131)

Answer (score 9):

The idea of Stackexcange network sites is to generate and provide content better than any other site out there. It's totally legit to ask quetions which are google-able.

In future, the challenge is to create outstanding questions and answers. The result will be that google mainly yields results from the Ethereum SE site. And if that happens, questions can be closed as duplicates, if they are google-able, if you know what I mean.

As for the Vitalik-question you linked, it's simply off-topic in my eyes.

Comment: While I agree my question is boarder line off-topic, I think it adds personality  to our stack exchange.  Vitalik responded with a similarly humorous response =)

Answer (score 6):

Don't think there's anything wrong with a question being googleable.  After all, ideally most of our future visitors will come from web traffic.  The problem with that question is that it doesn't meet the criteria of being ["based on actual problems that you face"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I agree that questions shouldn't be disqualified simply on the grounds that  answers are available elsewhere, but a lack of even cursory research probably shouldn't be encouraged.

Answer (score -2):

**Questions with extreme lack of research shouldn't be encouraged**

In some sites, they are downvoted but not voted closed; and others prefer to close them off.

And the question you have linked to, in your question is completely off-topic in the site!

Comment: I don't know about this.  The lack of research seems less important than whether or not a useful answer can be given that will provide genuine value to future site visitors.  In many cases lack of research just results in bad questions.  But naive questions can often still be answered to highly valuable effect.